# asp.net show different user login information

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

i newbie here,is there a way to show different user login information on w3-col s8 w3-bar?

i make it fix on master page and is on sidebar i need some help on this. 
Only Administrator login is the correct info because i make it fix,
if Bob login will show "Administrator" rather than Bob info.

Thanks.

```
     <nav class="w3-sidebar w3-collapse w3-white w3-animate-left" style="z-index:3;width:300px;" id="mySidebar"><br/>
  <div class="w3-container w3-row">
    <div class="w3-col s4">
      <img src="/images/logo.png" class="w3-circle w3-margin-right" style="width:46px"/>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-col s8 w3-bar">
      <span>Welcome, <strong>Administrator</strong></span><br/>
 <a><asp:LinkButton class="w3-button w3-red w3-padding-small" runat="server" OnClick="Logout" Text="logout"></asp:LinkButton></a> 
<div class="w3-bar-block">
    <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding-16 w3-hide-large w3-dark-grey w3-hover-black" onclick="w3_close()" title="close menu"><i class="fa fa-remove fa-fw"></i>Close Menu</a>
    <a href="FORMS/Stationary/Stationary.aspx" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Stationary</a>
    <a href="FORMS/Books/Books.aspx" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-padding"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>Books</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: if you want Administrator to change to different user then just make it a variable and assign it to that span... post some code

Comment: What? I have no idea what you are asking. Please rephrase your question to make it more clear. Also, it will be hard to help you if you do not post any of your code.

Comment: @ A GrammerPro i have update the question.

Comment: @sumeet kumar code update

Comment: what you want to change ?

Comment: i want to make the <span>Welcome, <strong>Administrator</strong></span><br/> dynamic for different user login it can be change.

Comment: Just change Administrator to a Javascript variable and update that element.. if you are using server side rendering then do it with that syntax

Answer (score 0):

If i am right you are trying to show different information according to user logged in.

If you using identity you can write like that:

if you only need display user name

```
<span>Welcome, <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong></span>
```

if you need to check what user logged in

```
@if(User.Identity.Name.Equals("Administrator"))
{
    <span>Welcome, <strong>Administrator</strong></span>
}
else if(User.Identity.Name.Equals("Bob"))
{
    <span>Welcome, <strong>Bob</strong></span>
}
```

And if you have some Roles u can check it like that

```
@if(User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
{
    <span>Welcome, <strong>Administrator</strong></span>
}
else 
{
    <span>Welcome, <strong>User</strong></span>
}
```

Comment: do you have the way of master page instead of mvc?